# how to get total items having date difference of more than 7

Tags: php, mysql

I have to do a mysql statement to get total items having date difference of more than 7 from today (means today - 7)

This is my current statement:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    complaints 
WHERE 
    complaint_status = 'OPEN' AND 
    complaint_regdate <= curdate()
    complaint_regdate >= DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 7 day)
```

I am getting this error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'complaint_regdate >= DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 7 day)' at line 1`

Comment: Whats wrong with your current statement?

Comment: I have edited my question with the error

Comment: The query in your question is logically wrong ( it doesn't do what you're asking to do, which after whitespace changes should be obvious ) and contains a syntax error which you should fix _before_ asking a question. And.. you just edited the question inserting the missing AND which makes the error message entirely irrelevant as it cannot come from the query now in the question.

Comment: -1. It's a fair question, but when you get answers, you should take the new information and try again. Even if a solution doesn't fully solve your problem, it may help you find the answer yourself - this is how we become better programmers.

Comment: @AD7six Got your point... really dont wanna mess up this great platform... slowly and gradually i'll learn..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the BETWEEN operator for this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM complaints 
WHERE complaint_status = 'OPEN' 
  AND complaint_regdate < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 day)
```

Note you don't need the DATE_SUB function, you can just use a normal subtraction.
Also these will only work if your `complaint_regdate` is a DATE column. If it's a DATETIME column you will need to use NOW() rather than CURDATE() or extract just the date pat of the field values.

Comment: Its giving me within 7 days not older than 7 days.

Comment: @AbhilashShukla Sorry, misread question, have updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also, if i want to do it for a month, should i add `INTERVAL 30 day` or some other efficient way is there to do it

Comment: @AbhilashShukla http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add You can use INTERVAL 1 MONTH.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing an AND operator in your sql.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM complaints WHERE complaint_status = 'OPEN' AND complaint_regdate <= curdate() AND complaint_regdate >= DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 7 day)
```

Comment: Its giving me within 7 days not older than 7 days.

Comment: @AbhilashShukla - you're missing the point of this answer. It fixes one of your errors; if you have other errors, you should respond to answers that discuss them. (Of course, once you get a fix for one error, you should try again to see if you can fix it yourself - it's the best way to learn!).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking for the query to find the count where the date is more than 7 days in the past. Your current query listed above shows the count for everything within the last 7 days. So here is the query for more than 7 days past:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM complaints WHERE complaint_status = 'OPEN' AND complaint_regdate < DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 7 day)
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'complaint_regdate < DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 7 day)' at line 1`